# PHP Fatal Error Call to Undefined. Stop it breaking page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Please forgive me if this is a duplicate question. I have searched but cant come up with an answer.

I am getting a PHP fatal error: call to undefined in my Wordpress site.

I know why this is, I am calling a method in my template file that is defined in a plugin - if the plugin isnt installed, then the template throws the error.

Is there any way I can encapsulate this method so that if it fails, the fatal error doesnt stop the rest of the page loading?

Many thanks.

Comment: Fatal errors tend to be... fatal. Why not try to solve the problem rather than bury it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not about 'burying' it, rather having a fallback that doesn't destroy the rest of the page. I can understand a fatal error for something like an infinite loop but for an undefined function that just pulls in some images it's a bit of overkill.

Comment: It's not overkill. You call an unknown function. How is the interpreter (PHP) supposed to know what to do? Imagine the called function is not "undefined" because of a typo, but because you forgot to include `security.php` and the function is authenticate_user_or_stop_execution(). Would you want the rest of the page to show in that case?

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton it's common practise in Wordpress themes to check if a certain plugin function is defined before calling it.

Comment: Overkill is the wrong word. What I want to do is 'contain' it. Checking if the function exists before calling makes sense as the poster below has said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the function is defined before calling it.

```
<?php 

if (function_exists('plugin_function')) {

    plugin_function();

} else {

   error_log('plugin is not activated');
   die();
}

?>
```